# Using a fuction which returns Future as usual function

Tags: flutter, dart

When we run a function which returns Future without `await` - will it execute synchronously?

Here is `UserPreferences.setUser(newUser);` returns Future.

Will this function wait the ending of `setUser` i.e. will it runs as synchronous function?
Or will the result of `setUser` be asynchronous?

```
return AppBar(
    ...
    actions: [
      ThemeSwitcher(
        builder: (context) => IconButton(
          icon: Icon(icon),
          onPressed: () {
            ...
            // this returns a Future
            UserPreferences.setUser(newUser);
          },
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: It will be asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will run async and will give you the result at anytime.

You can do like this, blocking the code execution until the function finishes:

```
String result = await UserPreferences.setUser();
```

Or you can do like this, not blocking the code execution and when it finishes the result will be given:

```
UserPreferences.setUser().then((value){
  String result = value;
});
```